# How to install a plugin in play framework 2.1

Tags: playframework-2.1

I am very new to Play framework and looking for steps to install play2-morphia-plugin in my application. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually a plugin's *readme* file contains an installation guide.

For the plugin you mentioned, a simple search leads to this [github issue about installing the plugin](https://github.com/leodagdag/play2-morphia-plugin/issues/4):

> To install this plugin, you have to add it in your project/Build.scala 
>   like this
>
> ```
> val appDependencies = Seq(
>   // Add your project dependencies here,
>   "leodagdag" % "play2-morphia-plugin_2.9.1" % "0.0.5"
> )
>
> val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA)
> .settings(
>   resolvers ++= Seq(DefaultMavenRepository, Resolvers.githubRepository, Resolvers.morphiaRepository)
> )
>
> object Resolvers {
>   val githubRepository = "LeoDagDag repository" at "http://leodagdag.github.com/repository/"
>   val morphiaRepository = "Morphia repository" at "http://morphia.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/"
> }
> ```